# How do I change the backgroud color of sidebar in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, background-color, sidebar, project-explorer

Recently, I got my laptop's screen upgraded to a beautiful matte finish Full HD model. Setting the Android Studio's background to a mild grey color is perfect for me but I can't find the option to change the background of the sidebar.

Please see the image I've attached. I've changed the editor's & console's background color, now only the sidebar's background remains to be altered.

Can anyone help me on this?

[image]